# Android Camera Set Resolution

Tags: android

I have built a custom Camera App and I am trying to change the resoloution of the image that is took. I have read around that this could depend on the phone or version of Android?

I know they are set using the `setParameters` but just dont know how to set the actuall resoloution to work on all phones. I am wanting it to be kind of small as my app force closes otherwise. When I use a test picture at 640x348 this works so around that size/resoloution would be perfect.

It may be easier to use `setPictureSize`?

```
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    camera = Camera.open();
    try {
           Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
           if (this.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation != Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
              parameters.set("orientation", "portrait");
              camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
              // Uncomment for Android 2.0 and above
              parameters.setRotation(90);
           } else {
              parameters.set("orientation", "landscape");
              camera.setDisplayOrientation(0);
              // Uncomment for Android 2.0 and above
              parameters.setRotation(0);
           }
          camera.setParameters(parameters);
          camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
      } catch (IOException exception) {
         camera.release();
       }
        camera.startPreview();
    }
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is no `setResolution()`, only `setPictureSize()`. Use `getSupportedPictureSizes()` on `Camera.Parameters` to find the size you want, or use that information to populate a `ListView` or `Spinner` or something for the user to choose the desired size. [Here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Camera/Picture) recently updated to use `getSupportedPictureSizes()` to find the smallest supported resolution and use that.

Comment: Ok cool is it possible for you to show me how to implement that I tried running your code from github but just getting errors from eclipse?

Comment: Also will the code check the supported sizes and then save it as the smallest, or does it need more?

Comment: @Matt: I cannot help you with "errors from eclipse" if you refuse to say what the errors are. And I have no idea what "more" is, and so I cannot say if the code needs it.

Comment: is it possible for you to join me in a Chat?

Comment: @Matt: If by "a Chat" you mean one of my office hours chats for subscribers to my books, sure. Beyond that, please open up a fresh StackOverflow question and ask your questions regarding this sample project. Tag it with `commonsware` and `android` so I pick it up, or post a link to the new question in a comment here.

Comment: Question is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8757341/android-reduce-size-of-camera-picture

Comment: Remember that setPictureSize() is not supported for some devices, for example Samsung Galaxy NOTE 4 and others

Answer (score 14):

It's too easy to capture image with **high quality**, here you can set your **own resolution**:

```
mCamera = Camera.open();
Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();

// Check what resolutions are supported by your camera
List<Size> sizes = params.getSupportedPictureSizes();

// Iterate through all available resolutions and choose one.
// The chosen resolution will be stored in mSize.
Size mSize;
for (Size size : sizes) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Available resolution: "+size.width+" "+size.height);
        mSize = size;
    }
}

Log.i(TAG, "Chosen resolution: "+mSize.width+" "+mSize.height);
params.setPictureSize(mSize.width, mSize.height);
mCamera.setParameters(params);
```

Hope this will help you all.

Comment: There is a list of resolutions and you can choose between a range. The highest resolution will be selected if you put a break; statement on the first find in this loop, and also you should avoid/check on runtime exception and OutOfMemory exception:  if (size.width >= 600 && size.width <= 800) {
                mSize = size;
                break;
            }

Comment: @AbhinavSaxena, yes, even we can choose anyone of them as required.

Comment: That was not a query instead a solution. I have added my solution in the comments. You can modify in your answer. Thanks.