# my taken snap does not appear in image view

Tags: android, layout, imageview, android-camera

I am trying to put my captured snap in the image view .For  bigger devices like nexus 7 and sony xperiac ,it is taking the snap ,but the image won't even show up and i can see that RESULT_OK ,by setting a flag bit .so what do i do now ?

```
package gatesapps.blogspot.com;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Random;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

String mCurrentPhotoPath;// for photo path
ImageView mImageView;
static boolean flag=false;

TextView tv;
Button test;
static final int REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mImageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.mImageView);
    tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
    test=(Button)findViewById(R.id.test);

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
@SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") @SuppressWarnings("unused")
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date(0, 0, 0));
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
        imageFileName,  /* prefix */
        ".jpg",         /* suffix */
        storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    mCurrentPhotoPath = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}

public void snap(View view){



Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
// Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    // Create the File where the photo should go
    File photoFile = null;
    try {
        photoFile = createImageFile();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        // Error occurred while creating the File

    }
    // Continue only if the File was successfully created
    if (photoFile != null) {
        takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
    }
}



}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        flag=true;
        test.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        setPic();

    }   

} 
private void setPic() {
    // Get the dimensions of the View
    int targetW = mImageView.getWidth();
    int targetH = mImageView.getHeight();

    // Get the dimensions of the bitmap
    BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);
    int photoW = bmOptions.outWidth;
    int photoH = bmOptions.outHeight;

    // Determine how much to scale down the image
    int scaleFactor = Math.min(photoW/targetW, photoH/targetH);

    // Decode the image file into a Bitmap sized to fill the View
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    bmOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor;
    bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);
    mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
```

Ans my xml is

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/mImageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:src="@drawable/back"
    android:contentDescription="preview of the pic"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter" 
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

 <Button 
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="Snap the picture"
   android:textColor="#3399FF"   
   android:onClick="snap"
   />
 <TextView 
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="75dp"
   android:text="Click snap the picture to take a pic"
   android:id="@+id/tv"
   android:textAlignment="center"
   android:textColor="#FF0000"
   android:textSize="25dp"
   />
 <Button 
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="Test"
   android:id="@+id/test"
   android:onClick="test"
   />
 </LinearLayout>
 </ScrollView>
```

Comment: Can you paste Log? I think it is due to low memory! Have you encountered MemoryOutOfBoundExeption?

Comment: I am testing this on phone ..

Comment: If you are phone is attached then you can surely see the Log :)

Comment: Is the data being passed back in the bundle extras valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Replace  mCurrentPhotoPath = "file:" +image.getAbsolutePath(); 
with    mCurrentPhotoPath =  image.getAbsolutePath();
```

Comment: what's the big difference ? @Palak

Comment: Very nice catch Palak! Although, this begs the question as to why OP's code worked for some devices. Good answer still. +1

Answer (score 1):

> but still the 1/4 th of the image on the image view is
>   existing(previously i am having an image in the imageview,i.e,before
>   taking the pic)

How do you define the ImageView with id `R.id.mImageView`? Make sure you don't have the background attribute set:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/mImageView"
    ....
    ....
    android:background="@drawable/originalDrawable" />
```

Instead, set the `src` attribute:

```
android:src="@drawable/originalDrawable"
```

Reason: The `background` fills the `ImageView`. `scaleType` works with the `src` drawable.
This is probably why you are seeing 1/4 of the old image. Oh, and, `setImageBitmap(bitmap)` sets the `src`.

I don't know why the pictures are not getting shown for `big` phones. I'll edit my answer if I figure that out.

Comment: yeah as you guessed ,previously it was background,now i kept source ,but still the problem exists,the image not getting showed up on bigger screens @Mrinali

Comment: edited my question with layout,thanks for addressing one issue ,address that setting the pic too .. i'll ive that 50 to you @Mrinali

Answer (score -1):

`data` returned with ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE intent result is only a thumbnail, very small bitmap intended to be put in a list or grid view. You must read the big image from the file if you want to fill the screen. You need scaling option when you decode from file to bitmap, otherwise on most devices you will be *outOfMemory*. See this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8758494/192373.

Comment: i have school now, i'll give you tick mark in the evening after the implementation of your solution (if it is correct ) @Alex