# Google Goggles Camera Autofocus

Tags: android, camera, camera-calibration, autofocus, google-goggles

The Google Goggles app auto-focuses considerably better than the default Camera app on my Nexus 4 (and other phones/tablets I tried on). In fact, it does it so good I think they do it software.

Does anyone know how the Goggles app does the autofocus or how to do it software?

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure the Google Goggles app shoots a lower resolution image than your standard camera app. Here is how you would set the resolution when launching the camera.[Android Camera Set Resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8744994/android-camera-set-resolution)