# my camera previewSize shows low resolution

Tags: android, surfaceview, preview

i'm on creating custom camera for android, but camera previewSize is showing low resolution , how can i make that to best preview size

this is the code for i used get previewSize

```
private Camera.Size getBestPreviewSize(int width, int height) {
        Camera.Size result = null;
        Camera.Parameters p = camera.getParameters();
        for (Camera.Size size : p.getSupportedPreviewSizes()) {
            if (size.width <= width && size.height <= height) {
                if (result == null) {
                    result = size;
                } else {
                    int resultArea = result.width * result.height;
                    int newArea = size.width * size.height;

                    if (newArea > resultArea) {
                        result = size;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return result;

    }
```

results of this code is shows `width: 352: height: 288`

using below code shows some other resolution

```
private Camera.Size getBestPreviewSize(int width, int height)
    {
        List<Size> sizes = camera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes();
        if (sizes == null) return null;

        Size optimalSize = null;
        double minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;

        int targetHeight = height;
        int targetWidth = width;

        int minWidthDiff = 0;
        if (optimalSize == null) {
            minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
            for (Size size : sizes) {
                if (Math.abs(size.width - targetWidth) < minDiff) {
                    if(size.width > width) {
                        if (minWidthDiff == 0) {
                            minWidthDiff = size.width - width;
                            optimalSize = size;
                        }
                        else if (Math.abs(size.width - targetWidth) < minWidthDiff) {
                            minWidthDiff = size.width - width;
                            optimalSize = size;

                        }   
                        minDiff = Math.abs(size.width - targetWidth);
                     }
                }
            }
        }

        if (optimalSize == null) {
            minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
            for (Size size : sizes) {
                if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                    optimalSize = size;
                    minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
                }
            }
        }
        return optimalSize;
    }
```

results of this code `width: 640 : height: 480`
but still preview looks blur

**EDIT:** stop preview before using it

```
camera.stopPreview();
parameters.setPreviewSize(size.width, size.height);
parameters.setRotation(0);
```

Comment: You may want to look at the cwac camera library, e.g. https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera/blob/master/camera/src/com/commonsware/cwac/camera/CameraUtils.java

Comment: i looked at that file but how to use that

Comment: See this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8744994/android-camera-set-resolution