# How can I get the default size (in pixels) of a photo which will be captured through Android camera, before capturing it?

Tags: android, android-camera, screen-resolution, android-camera2, android-resolution

If it is determined by the resolution of the Android device's screen, is there a way to programatically get the value of that resolution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If it is determined by the resolution of the Android device's screen

No.

> How can I get the default size (in pixels) of a photo which will be captured through Android camera

There is no "default size... of a photo".

If you are using the `android.hardware.Camera` or `android.hardware.camera2` APIs yourself, you need to specify the resolution that you want, from the available resolutions.

If you are using `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`, the resolution will be based in part on whether you pass `EXTRA_OUTPUT` or not, but otherwise is up to the camera app. There are thousands of Android device models, shipping with hundreds of different pre-installed camera apps, and there are many other camera apps available through distribution channels like the Play Store. They will be using the `android.hardware.Camera` or `android.hardware.camera2` APIs, and they will choose what resolution they want to use, by whatever algorithm they want.

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this

```
String pickedImagePath = "path/of/the/selected/file";
BitmapFactory.Options bitMapOption=new BitmapFactory.Options();
bitMapOption.inJustDecodeBounds=true;
BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pickedImagePath, bitMapOption);
int imageWidth=bitMapOption.outWidth;            
int imageHeight=bitMapOption.outHeight;
```

**Update:**

you can use display metrics to get your screen with

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

int width = metrics.widthPixels;
int height = metrics.heightPixels;
```

Note: The resolution of your screen and resolution of camera may not be the same. please refer the **[answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8747023/6414107)**.

Comment: Thank you, but I am sorry may be my question was not clear enough. I just edited the question statement. I meant to ask that I need the resolution even before the image is captured. Infact what I am after is the number of pixels (i.e. width and height of screen showing the live camera feed in pixels) of the live camera feed?

Comment: you want get the screen width and height in pixels, am i right?

Comment: Yes if the width and height of a camera frame in a full screen live camera feed is the same as the screen width and height?

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer and time. I had to accept the other one since that was more clear and comprehensive. But I upvoted a couple other good answers by you as a token of thanks.

Comment: @Solace: No problem, I have provided the  answer link from commonsware answer only

Answer (score 1):

Get the screen size using the following snippet. `this` means the current Activity context.

```
WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
Display display = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay();
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
display.getMetrics(displayMetrics);
int screenWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
int screenHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
```